# Typescript: Disallow directory imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, tsconfig, esmodules

I'm using typescript with https://npm.im/tsm in development and for builds I would love to stick with the Node LTS module resolution algorithm [at time of writing] that does not allow directory imports by default.

What is the set of `tsconfig` incantations that I need to enforce this in `tsc` builds?

EDIT: this is the error that node throws when you try to do a directory import, and this is the error I *want* to see when running `tsc` as well to enforce consistency:

```
@org/repo:dev: node:internal/process/esm_loader:48
@org/repo:dev:       internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
@org/repo:dev:                                 ^
@org/repo:dev: Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/jasonkurian/src/github.com/org/repo/apps/jobs/src/workers/sync/transform/tagging' 
is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/jasonkurian/src/github.com/org/repo/apps/jobs/src/workers/sync/transform/transform.ts
```

At the top of the `transform.ts` file I have this import to show the error:

```
import { tagging } from './tagging';
```

and it should be

```
import { tagging } from './tagging/index'; //or whatever the specific file is rather than importing the directory.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Originally shared in the TS discord: https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1147219641937178695 - you'll see there that Copilot chat gave me an incorrect answer.

Comment: Could you share the error message from build?

Comment: @khewdev edited to include an example of the underlying nodejs error I want to see. thanks!